# download file from DropBox to local Machine

Tags: java, upload, dropbox

I want to download a file from my dropbox account using java DropBox API. I have tried using this code but this is displaying the list of files and folder while i want to download files to my system how it is possible

Here's my code:-

```
Scanner tokenScanner = new Scanner(tokensFile);       
       String ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = tokenScanner.nextLine();    // Read key
       String ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = tokenScanner.nextLine(); // Read secret
       tokenScanner.close(); //Close Scanner
       //Re-auth
       AccessTokenPair reAuthTokens = new AccessTokenPair(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
       mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(reAuthTokens);
       Entry entries = mDBApi.metadata("/", 20, null, true, null);
       for (Entry e: entries.contents) {
        if(!e.isDeleted){
         if(e.isDir){
          System.out.println("Folder ---> " + e.fileName() );
         } else {
          //  this will download the root level files.
          System.out.println("File ---->" + e.fileName());
          DropboxInputStream inputStream = mDBApi.getFileStream(e.path,null);
          OutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(e.fileName());
          byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
          int len;
          while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0)
           out.write(buf,0,len);
               out.close();
               inputStream.close();
               System.out.println("File is created....");
```

Comment: dude you really need to fix your indentation ...

Comment: too much code! only post the relevant parts

Comment: @Philipp: I have removed unwanted code now please help me

Answer (score 9):

This is a basic example for downloading a file that work with dropbox. it does not include an progress of file download, this is just for straight forward file download.

This example uses dropbox API v2 using `DbxClientV2`

```
        try
            {
                //output file for download --> storage location on local system to download file
                OutputStream downloadFile = new FileOutputStream("C:\\.....");
                try
                {
                FileMetadata metadata = client.files().downloadBuilder("/root or foldername here/Koala.jpg")
                        .download(downloadFile);
                }
                finally
                {
                    downloadFile.close();
                }
            }
            //exception handled
            catch (DbxException e)
            {
                //error downloading file
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to download file to local system\n Error: " + e);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //error downloading file
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to download file to local system\n Error: " + e);
            }
```

Hope this helps and use this example and edit it to work the way you want it to work.

Comment: Excellent answer !